# Is there a way to translate within an html template before it's published to iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

I'm just an animal rescuer trying to finish building our new charity website and need some help with something, so please forgive me if I sound like a tech idiot (because I am).

We have a database of all the dogs and cats and can publish directly to our adoption web page via Service API. We can edit the html of the template within the database to change how the page looks. We've managed to get everything just how we like except for the iframe that pops up when a site visitor clicks on an animal for adoption. It gives more details about the dog or cat, and we need to translate the English text output so that it shows both English and Chinese in the iframe (eg. 'Dog' is translated to 'Dog 狗'.

There aren't too many words that need to be translated, so I just want to create some kind of small dictionary list within the html of the template so that any of the English words within it will be 'translated' into the bilingual output we want. I can edit the header, body, and footer of the template, and I've already successfully managed to translate the output from 'multiple choice' lookups using 'if' statements. But this won't work for the other single text output, like 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Yes', 'No', 'months', etc.

is there a way to do this? Is it something a tech idiot like me can do? We've managed to find ways to do this within the html of the web page itself but not the iframe. I just don't know how to do it or where the code should go.

Many thanks for any suggestions at all. We'd love to get the new website finished next week. I've searched this site but can't seem to find any answers.

Here's the template header, body, and footer currently. It may be messy . . .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>$$ANIMALNAME$$</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body { font-family: filson soft regular,sans-serif; text-align: 
center}
#mainpic { padding: 10px; margin-right: 15px; width: 90%; max- 
width: 600px; max-height: 600px border: 1px solid #555; 
background-color: #fff; box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888; border- 
radius: 0px; }
</style>
<meta property="og:title" content="$$ANIMALNAME$$" />
<meta property="og:description" content="$$ANIMALCOMMENTS$$" />
<meta property="og:image" content="$$WEBMEDIAFILENAME$$" />
</head>
<body>


<p><img id="mainpic" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;" src="$$WEBMEDIAFILENAME$$" /></p>
<h1 style="text-align: center; font-family: proxima soft 
extrabold,sans-serif; color: #c92327;">$$ANIMALNAME$$</h1>
<p style="text-align: center;">Time waiting for a home 入園時間: 
$$TimeOnShelter$$</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Energy level 活潑程度: 
$$EnergyLevel$$</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Breed 品種: $$BreedName$$</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Age 年龄: $$Age$$</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Size 體型: $$Size$$</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Sex 性別: $$Sex$$</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Weight 體重: $$Weight$$ kg  
$$Weight$$公斤</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Colour 毛色: 
$$BaseColourName$$</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Health problems 健康問題: 
$$HealthProblems$$</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Microchipped 有晶片: 
$$Microchipped$$</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Neutered 結紮: $$Neutered$$</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Fully vaccinated 已施打疫苗: 
$$AnimalsVaccinated$$</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Diet 主食: $$DietNameLast1$$</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Special needs 特殊需求: 
$$HasSpecialNeeds$$</p>
<script>
    if ('$$GoodWithCats$$' == 'Yes') document.write("<li>Good 
    with cats  可以跟貓相處</li>");
    if ('$$GoodWithDogs$$' == 'Yes') document.write("<li>Good 
    with dogs  可以跟狗相處</li>");
    if ('$$GoodWithChildren$$' == 'Yes') document.write(". 
    <li>Good with all children  可以和所有小孩相處</li>");
    if ('$$GoodWithChildren$$' == 'Unknown') document.write(". 
    <li>Not known if good with children  不知道能不能和小孩相處. 
    </li>");
    if ('$$GoodWithChildren$$' == 'Over 5') document.write(". 
    <li>Good with children over 5  可以和五歲以上的小孩相處</li>");
    if ('$$GoodWithChildren$$' == 'Over 12') document.write(". 
    <li>Good with children over 12  可以和12歲以上的小孩相處. 
    </li>");
    if ('$$HouseTrained$$' == 'Yes') document.write(". 
    <li>Housetrained  不會在家裡上廁所</li>");
    if ('$$GoodWithCats$$' == 'No') document.write("<li>Not 
    good with cats  不可以跟貓相處</li>");
    if ('$$GoodWithDogs$$' == 'No') document.write("<li>Not 
    good with dogs  不能跟狗相處</li>");
    if ('$$GoodWithDogs$$' == 'Selective') document.write(". 
    <li>Not good with all dogs  完全不能跟狗相處</li>");
    if ('$$GoodWithDogs$$' == 'Unknown') document.write(". 
    <li>Not known if good with dogs  不知道能不能和狗相處</li>");
    if ('$$GoodWithChildren$$' == 'No') document.write("<li>Not 
    good with children  不能和小孩相處</li>");
    if ('$$HouseTrained$$' == 'No') document.write("<li>Not 
    housetrained yet  有可能會在家裡上廁所</li>");
    if ('$$GoodWithCats$$' == 'Selective') document.write(". 
    <li>Not good with all cats  完全不能跟貓相處</li>");
    if ('$$GoodWithCats$$' == 'Unknown') document.write(". 
    <li>Not known if good with cats  不知道能不能和貓相處</li>");
    if ('$$HouseTrained$$' == 'Unknown') document.write(". 
    <li>Not known if housetrained  不知道會不會在家裡上廁所</li>");
    </script>
    <p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
    <h2 style="text-align: center; font-family: proxima soft 
    extrabold,sans-serif; color:#c92327;">Description 描述</h2>
    <p style="text-align: center;">$$AnimalComments$$</p>
    <p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
    <h2 style="text-align: center; font-family: proxima soft 
    extrabold,sans-serif; color:#c92327;">My Story 我的故事</h2>
    <p style="text-align: center;">$$MyStory$$</p>
    <p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>

<hr />
<p style="text-align: center; font-family: proxima soft 
extrabold,sans-serif;">ACT for Animals</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">社團法人台灣愛克特動物重生救援協會</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Code now added.